# Logstash doesn't import last line in txt file

Tags: elasticsearch, text, logstash, kibana, txt

I am trying to load a txt file into Elasticsearch with Logstash. The txt file is a simple text which consists of 3 lines, and it looks like this:

[text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwXgU.png)

My conf file looks like this:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:/Users/dinar/Desktop/myfolder/mytest.txt"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "NULL"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "mydemo"
        document_type => "intro"
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

After I run this and I go to Kibana, I can see the index being created. However, the only messages I see are the first two lines, and the last line is not displayed. This is what I see:

[Kibana page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSlME.png)

Does anybody know why the last line is not being imported and how I can fix this?

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: If you do not want the in-memory sincedb persisted across restarts on Windows you should set the sincedb_path to "NUL", not "NULL".

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshot, my assumption is that you are editing the file manually. In that case please verify, there is a newline after the last log entry: Just hit Enter & Save.